# substr function returning wrong result in php

Tags: php, vb.net, string, substring

I am a VB.NET developer working on a PHP project, I am trying to convert my VB.NET function into php, but not getting the desired result. After debugging I found a problem with substr function.

in VB.NET I am using

```
mid(105,2,1) 
This giving me output 0
```

but in php

```
substr(105,2,1)
Giving me output 5
```

Comment: read manual http://php.net/substr

Comment: I don't know how it is indexed in VB.NET, but for php it's index based 0, so change the 2 -> 1. Means e.g. `$str = "105";`  , `$str[0] -> 1` , `$str[1] -> 0` , `$str[2] -> 5`

Comment: `echo substr(105,1,1);`

Comment: Thanks Rizier123, I understand the issue and problem has been solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want get the `0` in **PHP** your code should be:

```
echo substr(105,1,1);
```

***Output:***

```
0
```

> If you want know why, read this:

`mid` function in **VB.NET**

```
Public Shared Function Mid( _
   ByVal str As String, _
   ByVal Start As Integer, _
   Optional ByVal Length As Integer _
) As String
```

> **str** - Required. String expression from which characters are returned.
>
> **Start** - Required. Integer expression. Starting position of the characters to return. If Start is greater than the number of characters in str, the Mid function returns a zero-length string (""). ***Start is one based***.
>
> **Length** Optional. Integer expression. Number of characters to return. If omitted or if there are fewer than Length characters in the text (including the character at position Start), all characters from the start position to the end of the string are returned.

***Example***

```
' Creates text string. 
Dim TestString As String = "Mid Function Demo" 
' Returns "Mid". 
Dim FirstWord As String = Mid(TestString, 1, 3)
' Returns "Demo". 
Dim LastWord As String = Mid(TestString, 14, 4)
' Returns "Function Demo". 
Dim MidWords As String = Mid(TestString, 5)
```

`substr` function in **PHP**

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

> **string** - The input string. Must be one character or longer.
>
> **start** - If start is non-negative, ***the returned string will start at the start'th position in string, counting from zero***. For instance, in the string 'abcdef', the character at position 0 is 'a', the character at position 2 is 'c', and so forth.
>
> If **start** is negative, the returned string will start at the start'th character from the end of string.
>
> If **string** is less than or equal to start characters long, FALSE will be returned.

***Example***

```
<?php
echo substr('abcdef', 1);     // bcdef
echo substr('abcdef', 1, 3);  // bcd
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 4);  // abcd
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 8);  // abcdef
echo substr('abcdef', -1, 1); // f
?>
```

Read more at:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: @Rizier123 You read the whole two pages (links)? And you can't see any aditional info in this links?

Comment: @Rizier123 I just want write a answer with some info useful to the question, and for do that I need write some explanation about the functions. Really I don't see what I do wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[substr()](http://php.net/substr) takes in 2 arguments and an optional third argument

> ( string, start position, *result length )

***note: result length**

- if +ve then offset from **start** of returned results,
- if -ve then offset from **end** of returned results

example:

```
   substr("abcde",2,1);

   // string: "abcde"
   // start position: 2  => returns "cde"
   // result length: 1  => returns "c"


   substr(105,2,1);

   // string: "105"
   // start position: 2  => returns "5"
   // result length: 1  => returns "5"
```

You can [test substr online here](https://www.functions-online.com/substr.html). Hope this helps.